# Flask (with Flask-RESTful) not parsing JSON payloads

Tags: flask, flask-restful

I'm creating a frontend in Angular, and the backend in Flask with the RESTful extension. By default, Angular likes to send data back as a payload (eg this is what it appears like in Chrome Developer tools: [image: chrome developer payload]). I am also aware it can easily format this in to a JSON payload, which will be preferable for a few other cases on other endpoints.

What is the best way to use the argument parser in RESTful to deal with this? If I encode things as form data they can be read by reqparse, but not just a raw payload like this (although from reading their [documentation](http://flask-restful.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reqparse.html) and source, it seems like it should be able to handle more than this). I am aware that by using the 'location' arg in reqparse it will look [elsewhere](http://flask-restful.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reqparse.html#other-locations) (by default it looks in `form` and `json`). However, anything not sent via form fields does not seem to be parsed, despite anything I try (Even when explicitly setting location to include every attribute of the `request`, eg json, args). Sample code appears like:

```
class Login(restful.Resource):

    def __init__(self):
        self.parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
        self.parser.add_argument('user', type=str, required=True)
        self.parser.add_argument('passw', type=str, required=True)

    def post(self):
        args = self.parser.parse_args()

        # Some logic here
        return self.response
```

Is there something I am doing wrong to not be able to read args?

Answer (score 7):

You will, I think, need to do the following:

(1) Make `location='json'` explicit in `add_argument`:

```
self.parser.add_argument('user', type=str, location='json', required=True)
self.parser.add_argument('passw', type=str, location='json', required=True)
```

(2) Ensure the header field `Content-Type` of the http request from the client is `application/json`

(3) The request payload should look like this:

```
{
  "user": "abc",
  "passw": "123456"
}
```

I routinely parse JSON requests with flask-restful without any trouble.  One small difference is that I don't have my request parser as an instance field of the resource.  Not sure if that is causing you trouble, but it might be worth a try to move it out if you are still stuck.